# why my If statment dont work with or in my Case -python date validation from automate the boringstuff with python

Tags: python, date, validation, if-statement

```
import re
ausgabe =[]
Datum = re.compile(r"([0-2][1-9]|[3][0|1])(\/)([0-1][0-9])(\/)([0-2][0-9]{3})")     #filter
Daten =(" 31/12/2000 blub 31.02.2000 und 32/01/2099 blub 28/02/2000 29/09/2009 29/39/2009 ") #Datenstr
ausgabe =Datum.findall(Daten)     #durchsuchen

month = None
day = None
year = None

for Datum in ausgabe:
    allright = True
    day = int(Datum[0])
    month =int(Datum[2])
    year = int(Datum[4])
 #   print(day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "\n", end="")

    if month == 4 or 6 or 11: #if the month is 4, 6,11
        print(month)
        if day > 30:    #check the days of the month
            allright= False

    elif month == 2:
        if day > 28:
            print("feb hat nur 28 tage")
            allright = False
    elif day > 31:
            print("größer als 31")
            allright = False

if allright == True:
    print(str(day) + "/" + str(month) + "/" + str(year) + "\n", end="")
```

Problem is in the **following** line.
The month is 12 and it jumps into the next if statement inside and checks this
but also if isnt 4 6 and 11. This is out of automate the boring stuff with python.

i just started coding some weeks ago so maybee its super easy to see...
i rewatched some videos and thougth about it but i dont understand this

```
if month == 4 or 6 or 11: #if the month is 4, 6,11
        print(month)
        if day > 30:    #check the days of the month
            allright= False
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if month == 4 or 6 or 11: #if the month is 4, 6,11
```

you should use

```
if month == 4 or month == 6 or month == 11: #if the month is 4, 6,11
```

The

```
if month == 4 or 6 or 11:
```

Is interpreted by Python as

```
if (month == 4) or (6) or (11):
```

while `6` and `11` are positive integers interpreted by Python as `True`
As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true)